# How do I only get the latest input from tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to get only the latest input from my text widget, and then append that character to a list.
I am using
`Text.get(1.0,'end-1c')`
, and it does not work because the loop constantly gets all the input, instead of only getting the latest input when there is a new latest input.

```
def main_screen():
    start_time=time.time()
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title('Typing Test')
    tk.geometry('800x500')
    main_title=Label(tk,text='1 Minute Test',font=('Times New Roman',36))
    main_title.pack(pady=5)
    directions=Label(tk,text='Start Typing',font=('Times New Roman',14))
    directions.pack()
    base_text=Label(tk,text=randomizer(),bg='#E0E0EE',font=('Arial',14),wraplength=700,justify=LEFT)
    base_text.pack(pady=10)
    text_area=Text(tk,font=('Arial',14),width=63,height=7,wrap='word')
    text_area.pack()
    tk.update()
#WPM Calculation
    target_text=randomizer()
    typed_text=[]
    wpm=0
    errors=0
    while True:
        tk.update()
        time_elapsed=max(time.time()-start_time,1)
        wpm=round((len(typed_text)/60)/5)
        if time_elapsed>=60:
            break
#Problem Section
        key=text_area.get(1.0,'end-1c')
        typed_text.append(key)
        for x in typed_text:
            if x != target_text:
                errors += 1
```

Alternatively, I tried using a variable in place of the 1.0 in .get, that would increase by one with each iteration of the loop. Next, I tried a try/except command, and put the #Problem Section into a function. I tried calling that function by binding the text area to

```
'<Key>'
'<KeyPress>'
'<KeyRelease>'
```

None of these attempts work. I used a print statement to see what those variables are with each iteration of the loop, and using the first method, it just keeps making a longer and longer string that repeats constantly, instead of updating with each new character. Trying the other ways I just got nothing, no output, but no error either. I am completely stuck, and don't know what else to try.

Comment: Is data only ever appended to the widget? What if the user inserts data at the start of the widget? How do you expect it to behave in that case?

Comment: @BryanOakley, thank you for commenting, but I don't really understand what you're saying. Maybe my question was a little unclear. I am trying to get the latest input, and then append it to a list, so that I can compare it to my target text for errors. I used the answer provided by below, and it is working for the most part. I hope this clears up the problem I was having.

Comment: Let's say the user types five lines of text, and you grab that text to do whatever processing you want. Now, if the user clicks at the top of the widget and inserts a new line before the first line instead of typing at the end, what do you expect to happen? Do you only want to get the new characters they've typed? Or everything from the start of where they typed to the end?

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh, I see what you're saying now. It should only receive the new characters, not all the text in the box. It is a typing test app, so I just didn't expect them to click and start typing somewhere else in the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `text_area` with a `<KeyPress>` event, but you need to pass the list `typed_text` as an argument so you can append the presses.

So you should do something like this:

```
text_area.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda _: getKey(_, typed_text))
    while True:
        tk.update()
        time_elapsed = max(time.time() - start_time, 1)
        wpm = round((len(typed_text) / 60) / 5)
        if time_elapsed >= 60:
            break
        # Problem Section
        for x in typed_text:
            if x != target_text:
                errors += 1


def getKey(event, list):
    list.append(event.char)
    print(list)
```

Comment: Thank you @DonPre ! This works really well based on the printed output, but I am still receiving crazy high error numbers. Is this because of the empty string at the beginning of the list changing the order of the comparison, or is it how I am calculating the errors?

Comment: You are calculating the errors in a wrong way: every time you iterate in the while loop, you count the errors all over the list again. You can try to add something like `typed_text.pop(-1)` after the if statament

Comment: Oh thanks. I don't know how I missed that. I am now calculating both wpm and errors after the while loop breaks. I tried `typed_text.pop(-1)`, `typed_text.pop(0)`, and `typed_text.clear()`. None of them worked. I don't know what you mean by after the if statement. Do you mean the one in the while loop or in the for loop? Because I moved the for loop calculating errors to later in the program, so it would not work for that. I think now that I am calculating the errors only once, that this is the problem.

Comment: Without seeing your code is difficult to get you a correct answer, so if you need more help you can ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The text widget supports something called a "mark", which is like a bookmark. You can put a mark anywhere in the text and use it just like a normal index.

Assuming that data is only ever appended to the end of the widget, the simplest solution is to fetch a block of data and then move the mark to the end of the text that you fetched. The next time you fetch data, start at that mark.

Marks have something called "gravity" that defines which character the mark sticks to. For example, if the gravity is "left" and you set it to character "2.2", the mark will always stay adjacent to the character at index "2.2". If the gravity is "right", it will be stuck at the character following index "2.2" (eg: "2.3" or "3.0")

Here's a contrived example that will print only the latest additions to a text widget every five seconds, by tracking the last position that was used to fetch the data.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_new_text():
    data = text.get("last", "end-1c")
    print(f"new data: >>>{data}<<<")
    text.mark_set("last", "end-1c")
    root.after(5000, get_new_text)

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.mark_set("last", "1.0")
text.mark_gravity("last", "left")

root.after(5000, get_new_text)

root.mainloop()
```